# Code::Blocks - a quicker way to add new files

Tags: codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks 16.0.1. Now, when I'd like to add a new C source file I have to navigate using my mouse a lot: go to the file submenu, select File, select C/C++ source, select the directory to create it in - too much mouse usage!!

Is there any way to do it more quickly? I'd rather right click on the destination directory, to add the file there, for example.\

Still, I'd like to get a template with the include guards.

Answer (score 0):

Drag & drop directly into the left-tree, under Sources or project icon.

Comment: But I'd like to make use of the templates. And drag&drop isn't very comfortable on a touchpad.